# What is Xtext 2.10's equivalent of generateJavaMain?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, xtext

In order to create a standalone command-line compiler, using older Xtext versions, the following had to be added to the .mwe2 Workflow definition (according to page 94 in Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend, Packt publishing, Lorenzo Bettini):

```
fragment = generator.GeneratorFragment {
     generateJavaMain = true
}
```

This generated a Main-Class that could be used as an entry point in a runnable JAR file.

How can I achieve this goal in Xtext 2.10?

Answer (score 5):

Just found it in the [Xtext forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1726013/?srch=generateJavaMain#msg_1726013):

```
....
language = StandardLanguage {
....
    generator = {
        generateJavaMain = true
    }
....
}
....
```

....